# Linked list trouble

Tags: c, list, linked-list

Does anyone know what might be the problem with the following code? When I run it, I get the following output:

```
Insert a value in the list: 1
Do you want to continue? y/N: 
 1 ->
```

The fact is that the do-while loop executes until the `scanf("%c", &ch)` statement, and then it jumps out (so I cannot provide any input for the `ch` variable). I tried debugging with GDB and I got some weird messages:

```
GI___libc_malloc (bytes=16) at malloc.c:malloc.c: No such file or directory.
```

Also, it says that the compiler couldn't find the `vscanf.c` file. Does anyone have an explanation for this strange behavior? Thanks! (The intention was to print the values of a singly linked list in reverse order.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int info;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* head = 0;

void add_node(int value){

     struct node* current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     current->info = value;
     current->next = head;
     head = current;
 }

void print_node(struct node* head){

     while(head){

          printf(" %d -> ", head->info);
          head = head->next;
     }

     printf("\n");
 }

int main(void){

    int val;
    char ch;

    do {

       printf("Insert a value in the list: ");
       scanf("%d", &val);
       add_node(val);
       printf("Do you want to continue? y/N: ");
       scanf("%c", &ch);

    } while(ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');

    printf("\n");
    print_node(head);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: A complete shot-in-the-dark here, could the second `scanf` be reading in a newline?

Comment: change method signature of add_node to accept a struct node* parameter, then pass the address of head as an argument to your function call. That should do it.

Comment: The GDB messages are serving to inform you that you cannot step into GLIB files, just press c to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is because the  once you type a value for `val` and then press enter , then `\n` still remains in the input buffer . Hence , the next `scanf` assumes  that `\n` which is still in the input buffer is its input , and consumes it and then loop exits .

Other Solutions  :-

1) `scanf("%d%*c",&val);`

This would assign the first input character to `val` and then anything after that would be eaten up . Hence , the `\n` would not go into the next `scanf`

2) `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&val);`

This would assign the anything  to the `val` except `\n` and then `\n` would be eaten up .

Answer (score 2):

If you want the input to be separated by a new line (which it appears that you do) then change the format of how you are reading in your character. Change following:

```
scanf( "%c", &ch );
```

... to this:

```
scanf( "\n%c", &ch ); // << Note, \n to pickup newline before reading the value.
```

Comment: If that were actually the problem, couldn't he just do `scanf("%d\n", &val);` instead of doing two `scanf`s?

Comment: When you do `scanf("%d\n", &val);`, the program waits for something other than enter, and it just prints and exits after you enter something.

Comment: @Jacob, I got the idea behind using `'\n'`, thanks. But, As I know `scanf()` ignores `'\n'` character. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ErcanOzturk, no I recommended that as a solution to this 27 minutes ago, however I had the giant block of code. I decided to remove the giant block of code in my edit, not change my solution -- see the history.

Comment: @ErcanOzturk I guess I'm just wondering if that is specifically in the spec for `scanf`, I wouldn't be terribly surprised.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for proper input in an if-else block, and execute your code accordingly.
For example, here is something I would do if I needed to check whether the user wants to continue or not:

```
char chTemp; //Declare a test variable to check for newline
printf("Do you want to continue? y/N: ");
if (scanf("%c%c",&ch,&chTemp) != 2 || chTemp != '\n')
{
     printf("Error in input (Integer input provided)");
}
else
{
     //Do stuff.
}
```

Not only will it solve your problem, but it will also check for careless integer inputs.